# Geoprocessing Service Cannot Download Result?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, clip, geoprocessing-service

I have implement the ArcGIS JavaScript example just like the ESRI official example ([clip and ship](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/gp/gp_clipasync.html)) .Everything was going right except the final step ,when the gp job have finish and my browser lead me to the result URL it have show the 404 Error.
I checked out the gp job directory which do contain the job results(output.zip).At the same time i had add the server's hostip and hostname in my hosts file.

My  Environment: Window 2003 Sp2 ,ArcGIS Server 10, Chrome 18;

I am using the java version which the web server is tomcat 6.

Comment: When you say Tomcat, do you mean a separate tier altogether, or the tomcat thats bundled under the hood of the Java edition?

Comment: Also add to your Q what you have as your virtual directories (particularly the arcgisjobs one):
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_java_help/index.html#/Creating_a_server_directory_in_Manager/0092000000mz000000/

Comment: did u find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You may need to add support for the .zip mime type to your IIS server because  IIS 6.0 requires you to add new mime types before you can download files or else it throws a 404 error.

Try reading the following: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/cd72c0dc-c5b8-42e4-96c2-b3c656f99ead.mspx

You need to add the .zip application/zip mime type to your web server.

Comment: Sorry.My mistake.I am using java version ,so it using tomcat 6 as the web server.